# Create & Access Changesets and More TFS SDK C#

Tags: c#, tfs, sdk

**I have hit a road block.**

I have to create new folder & files inside Branch which I have managed to do. Now, my goal is to add some data in the files and TFS will create the Changesets for each change to these files. This also I managed. Later I want to access these changesets.

Three Issues.

1. Every time I create files I have to create a temporary Workspace,map it to local folder, create a file and then add & CheckIn. Now, is there an alternative to that? Is it possible to directly create a file with out going through the whole thing?
2. Every time I have to edit the file I have to repeat the same as above.Create Workspace, Map it locally, Download the file, Edit, CheckIn. Only then TFS creates a changeset. Can we somehow overcome that and directly edit the files in the TFS branch and still have changesets?
3. I can retrieve and compare the code in different changesets but for that too I have to download the file and compare them using code or a tool. Is there a way to directly retrieve and display all changesets and let the user decide which one to select??

My goal is to create branches. Inside the Branches I will create subfolders and store data in files. These files will store JSON object or XML. Content of the files will be some table related data. Whenever there are any changes to the file TFS will create changesets. These changesets will actually be a sort of history for the data in my files. Later I want to display all changesets and let user chose from the available changesets.

I know how to do all that but there is lot of overhead of Creating temp workspaces, mapping them, then changing , CheckIn and so on...

**QUESTIONS**

1. *Is there a way I can resolve the Three Issues above? Or is there any other way to do this? Any Tool or API? How about the new REST API for TFS. Can it resolve my issues?*
2. *If there is no other way and I have to go with the current approach with all the overhead. Is it a good practice? How can it work through a Service?*

-Sam

Comment: Do you want to add/edit files programmatically with TFS API or just do it in IDE? Additionally, if you already create a local workspace for TFS, it is not necessary for you to create temp workspace every time.

Comment: Well, Thanks for some reply here. No IDE involved. Have to get it done through API. Create a LOCAL workspace for TFS? We currently I create a TEMP workspace. Execute my operations and delete the workspace! The reason I do it is. There are several hundreds of users. If they are all working on the same workspace and same file. There will be deadlocks and read/write issues. And creating workspace for each user is not a option for me. Simply there are too many of them and increasing each day!

Comment: If you don't want to create a temp workspace, you need to create a local workspace. Local workspace actually locates on user's local machine.  Any concern why don't create workspace for each user?

Comment: BECAUSE these requests will come from a REST service and run through a layer on the TFS. Cannot create Workspace on users local machine.

Comment: We have made some progress. Now we plan to Map each Client to Single workspace. So some of the issues are sorted out. 

But, I would like to know if we can directly edit the files in Server Workspace without having to MAP them to Local Workspace??

Sam

Comment: This issue is now resolved. We have managed to map pretty much everything except for change sets. We are trying to create backdated changesets and push through. But anyway it works for us. We are using Temporary work space for each request.